# Wine fails to install, says broken package held. Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (Backslash Kristoff)

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I dont know what to do anymore.

```
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ sudo apt-get -s install wine
[sudo] password for vstev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) wine-stable [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.0.4~xenial > ( otherosfs )
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable-i386 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none ) (= 3.0.4~xenial)
Considering wine-stable-i386:i386 0 as a solution to wine-stable:amd64 0
Holding Back wine-stable:amd64 rather than change wine-stable-i386:amd64
Investigating (0) winehq-stable [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.0.4~xenial > ( otherosfs )
Broken winehq-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.0.4~xenial > ( otherosfs ) (= 3.0.4~xenial)
Considering wine-stable:amd64 0 as a solution to winehq-stable:amd64 -1
Holding Back winehq-stable:amd64 rather than change wine-stable:amd64
Investigating (1) wine [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Considering wine1.6:amd64 1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Re-Instated ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64
Re-Instated wine1.6-amd64:amd64
Re-Instated binfmt-support:amd64
Reinst Failed early because of wine1.6-i386:amd64
Considering wine1.6:amd64 1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Re-Instated wine-staging-amd64:amd64
Reinst Failed early because of libasound2:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-staging-i386:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-staging:amd64
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Reinst Failed early because of libasound2:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-stable-i386:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-stable:amd64
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Re-Instated wine-devel-amd64:amd64
Reinst Failed early because of libasound2:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-devel-i386:i386
Reinst Failed because of wine-devel:amd64
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Investigating (1) wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6:any [ any ] < none ->  > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2)
Considering wine1.6:amd64 1 as a solution to wine1.6-amd64:amd64 0
Holding Back wine1.6-amd64:amd64 rather than change wine1.6:any:any
Investigating (2) wine [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Considering wine1.6:amd64 1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering wine1.6:amd64 1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-staging:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-stable:amd64 -1 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Considering winehq-devel:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9997
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ dpkg --get-selections|grep hold
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-xenial.list
fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-xenial.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list.save
tista-ubuntu-adapta-xenial.list
tista-ubuntu-adapta-xenial.list.save
ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ apt -cache madison wine
E: Opening configuration file ache - ifstream::ifstream (2: No such file or directory)
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ apt-cache madison wine 
  wine | 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  wine | 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
vstev@X-13-33Vs:~$ apt-cache show wine   
Package: wine
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: extra
Section: universe/otherosfs
Source: wine1.6
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 6
Depends: wine1.6
Filename: pool/universe/w/wine1.6/wine_1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb
Size: 976
MD5sum: c9d67cc5e90b511546bfadf8832b0fdd
SHA1: 267119c3584bf7e3db505fe5279cf4b8b8011a9d
SHA256: 0292f5e9fd089904eecbf09c9c911734a9d20bbe79a615c99970a3369154c091
Homepage: http://www.winehq.org/
Description: Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)
Description-md5: 6474b3e541944944e61aec502ceb28f2
Package: wine
Priority: extra
Section: universe/otherosfs
Installed-Size: 6
Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: wine1.6
Version: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14
Depends: wine1.6
Filename: pool/universe/w/wine1.6/wine_1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb
Size: 974
MD5sum: bea5bed393084b4406fcda336325bc71
SHA1: 12cb87640d0cb8a707ce2e89ebd872e5e32c8c9b
SHA256: ab68e0b0f6122e5d189171242a3fc706cd8689ed45feb25b3140530f17c81188
Description: Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)
Description-md5: 6474b3e541944944e61aec502ceb28f2
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: http://www.winehq.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

$ sudo apt-get install wine32
```

After success installing you can try any command:

```
wine32 /path/to/mustdie.exe

wine /path/to/mustdie.exe

./wine32 /path/to/mustdie.exe
```

P.S: Probably, do you use x86-64 arch.

P.S.2: In russia we use word "mustdie" for meaning windows.